# What are the sphinx default templates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

There is a `layout.html` template that can be overwritten. There are more, right? What are they and where can I find the original code? I would like to see what the default templates look like so I can customize accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to edit templates directly in the Sphinx package. It is best to override them locally. How to do so is documented in [Templating](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html).

To determine which files you can override also depends on the theme you are customizing. Sphinx's default themes are located where you installed the Sphinx package, e.g., in your project's virtual environment at `env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/themes/basic`.